# How to Uniquely associate nested call with the original call?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unity-container

I have function that is using unity interception to log the method time. The problem comes when I want to log deeper info like database call time, backend time etc.

So my method (let say, M1) calls some other method(M2) that inturn call some other method and so on to finally call a dbMethod that calls db. I am able to log time for all functions individually but for final aggregation in my log server , it would be helpful if I can find for which M1 call, how much time the dbServer Method took.

So is there some property like threadId that I can use that remain same during the nested calls so that I can use them in final aggregation (for joining M1 and dbMethod log data)? I would like that unique value to be different in different invokation of M1.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone out there that is facing same problem, I solved it using CallContext class. Just add a request Id in outermost call and it will propagate to all the inner nested call.